# Setting required action on new keycloak user account

Tags: keycloak

I am using a client to create a new keycloak user. Something like this:

```
keycloak.realm(realm)
        .users()
        .create(user);
```

The user variable is a `UserRepresentation` object, and I'm trying to add an `Update Password` required action:

```
user.setRequiredActions(singletonList("Update Password"))
```

User gets created ok, the problem is that I don't have the required action set

[image]

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, should I specify a different value in the required actions list?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Figured out what was up.

Keycloak has an enum to represent various user actions:

```
public static enum RequiredAction {
    VERIFY_EMAIL, UPDATE_PROFILE, CONFIGURE_TOTP, UPDATE_PASSWORD, TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS
}
```

So the value should be `"UPDATE_PASSWORD"` not `"Update password"`

Comment: Actually, this is very incomplete. This enum it's part of a class that is called UserModel, and belongs to a very precise lib called keycloak-server-spi.

Answer (score 6):

To find out all the possible required actions aliases, export your targeted realm as json from the admin interface. In the json you will find the "requiredActions" array in which all the legal actions are listed like so:

```js
 "requiredActions": [
    {
      "alias": "CONFIGURE_TOTP",
      "name": "Configure OTP",
      "providerId": "CONFIGURE_TOTP",
      "enabled": true,
      "defaultAction": false,
      "priority": 10,
      "config": {}
    },
    {
      "alias": "terms_and_conditions",
      "name": "Terms and Conditions",
      "providerId": "terms_and_conditions",
      "enabled": false,
      "defaultAction": false,
      "priority": 20,
      "config": {}
    },
```

Just use the string under the "alias" tag when setting the list of required actions in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Now in Keycloak 8.x you can use

```
UserResource.toRepresentation().setRequiredActions(...);
```

to manually trigger an action like "verify email" after changing the loginname.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to verify Required Actions in a custom Keycloak endpoint. Unfortunately, using the `RequiredAction` enum only works for built-in Required Actions.

In order to obtain my list of custom Required Actions, I did the following:

```
// MyCustomRealmResourceProvider implements RealmResourceProvider
...
List<String> availableRequiredActions = session
        .realms()
        .getRealm(realm.getName())
        .getRequiredActionProvidersStream()
        .map(RequiredActionProviderModel::getProviderId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This returns a list a of all Required Action IDs.